# jupyter nbconvert command works well while 'download as' menu command causes error "xelatex not found on PATH"

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am using jupyter-notebook on macOS.

I've installed MacTeX and successfully converted notebook to pdf with command.

```
jupyter nbconvert test.ipynb --to pdf
```

when I use 'download as' menu command, I encountered this error.

> nbconvert failed: xelatex not found on PATH, if you have not installed xelatex you may need to do so. Find further instructions at https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-tex.

what am I missing?